# react-transition-group conditionally animate out

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

I'm trying to use `react-transition-group` to add some animation to a list that I have.

This is my general setup, I have list component that renders a number of children. There are a number of interactions that cause items to be added/removed from this list. Some of these actions need to cause the component to be removed using an animation but I can't seem to get that working and I'm guessing maybe I'm missing something here.

This is my basic setup:

```
<TransitionGroup className="list" component="ul">
   {this.props.item.map(item => (
      <CSSTransition key={item.id} timeout={500} classNames="fade" enter={false} exit={!!item.shouldAnimate}>
        <ChildComponent/>
      </CSSTransition>
    ))}
</TransitionGroup>
```

I have verified that everything is fine in my state logic (i.e. `shouldAnimate` is set to `true` as I expect but it still doesn't animate.

Any suggestions?

Edit:
Created a fiddle showing the problem and I think I now see the issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/af0ee2eo/2/

As I described above I don't know until the user takes an action if that action should be one that causes the item to be animated or not when it is removed from the list. I'm setting `shouldAnimate` correctly but then before the next render I'm removing that item from the list. If I delay the removal until after the next render things work okay but that's annoying to have to do every time (this is what I am demonstrating by the "Use Delay?" checkbox at the bottom of the fiddle). I wish there was a way to inject state into the state of the item held by TransitionGroup's component state.

If anyone has any other idea how I might fix this without a `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame` render hack let me know otherwise I'll just mark this question as answered.

Comment: try positing at-least the complete code of the map function. The map function seems to be not closed and if this is your actual code it should give you syntax errors

Comment: Thx for pointing that out. I fixed the syntax error but the full code would probably be more in the way than anything. All that was missing here was closing the map function.

Comment: then shall i add it as an answer so that everybody knows it is closed ?

Comment: Oh no sorry that wasn't what I meant. I was saying that was just the problem with the posted code snippet. This problem still exist.

Comment: Added a fiddle above and I think I see the issue (which should have been more obvious before) but still wishing there is a workaround for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out and just in case someone else comes along and see this the answer is to use the `childFactory` prop. It allows you to change prop values on leaving children.

Link with more info: https://medium.com/lalilo/dynamic-transitions-with-react-router-and-react-transition-group-69ab795815c9